# Multi Value Setting (Settings.bundle) issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I just can't get Multi Value settings to work in my Ipad app.
This is my plist code for the multi value:

```
<dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSMultiValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>DefaultValue</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>0</string>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Project</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>project</string>
    </dict>
```

I already tried everything, reset the iPad simulator, added other settings... and multi values keep on not showing in the settings. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved this by defining the array of "Titles". It won't show the setting without it.

Comment: You're right - I assumed that if I was creating a Multi-Value settings option, then it would automatically add all the needed parameters, but 'Titles' must be added (in addition to 'Title').

Titles corresponds to the actual data in the multi-value selections, so make sure to put the corresponding titles in the same order as the values they're tied to.